# jQuery each field inside parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, each

I'm trying to build a common clear fields button that has the following html structure:

```
<td colspan="2">
    <input type="text" name="unpublish_date" id="unpublish_date" class="calendar" />
    <img class="clear_date" src="ico_delete.gif" title="Reset date field"></span>
    <input type="hidden" name="_unpublish_date" id="_unpublish_date" />
</td>
```

So I though that the right way to do the function is by working with the inputs, inside the parent of `.clear_date`

What I would like to know is how to select each input after `$(this).parent`

```
$('.clear_date').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().each() ... ?
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).parent().find('input').each() ...
```

See [jQerty `.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 4):

Just use `.siblings` with a filter:

```
$(this).siblings('input').each()...;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
$(this).parent().find("input").each(function(){
    $(this).val("");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.clear_date').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().each(function() {
        $(this).val("");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input', $('.clear_dates').parent()).each(function
{
  ...
});
```

or

```
$('.clear_dates').parent().find('input').each(function
{
  ...
});
```

You can of course replace $('.clear_dates') with $(this) so:

```
$('input', $(this).parent()).each(function
{
  ...
});
```

or

```
$(this).parent().find('input').each(function
{
  ...
});
```